# Internal SSD and SMART status

Tags: macos, ssd, storage

I just ran Etrecheck on my iMac. I got a status report on my internal 250 GB solid state drive. The report stated the drive has SMART capability but that it was disabled.  Is this an issue I should be concerned with?  Does it affect the speed or other functionality of this drive. Most of my software is located on this drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Is [SMART being disabled] an issue I should be concerned with? Does it affect the speed or other functionality of this drive.

SMART is a monitoring and reporting tool.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.):

> S.M.A.R.T. (Self-Monitoring, Analysis and Reporting Technology; often
> written as SMART) is a monitoring system included in computer hard
> disk drives (HDDs) and solid-state drives (SSDs) that detects and
> reports on various indicators of drive reliability, with the intent of
> enabling the anticipation of hardware failures.

It has no effect whatsoever on the performance of your SSD.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar request over at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/10326/do-ssds-support-smart#10336). The recommendation there is to enable it, since SSDs over time would also develop hardware defects that SMART can detect/anticipate. So while it doesn't affect speed, it's a safety net.

Comment: how do you enable it?